# Sharing Pika Connection Singleton Object between gunicron workers on django application

Tags: django, rabbitmq, singleton, gunicorn, pika

I am trying to connect to email queue from django application. I have created an EmailPublisher which will be a singleton object which extends RabbitMQProducer object which has actual code of connecting to rabbitmq service. Now I want to share the rabbitmq connection between gunicorn workers how can I do this? I am using python 3.7
with django.

```
class RabbitMQProducer(ABC):

    def __init__(self):

        self.credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(
            settings.RABBITMQCONFIG['username'],
            settings.RABBITMQCONFIG['password'],
        )

        self.parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=settings.RABBITMQCONFIG['host'],
            port=settings.RABBITMQCONFIG['port'],
            virtual_host=settings.RABBITMQCONFIG['virtual_host'],
            credentials=self.credentials,
            heartbeat=600,
            blocked_connection_timeout=300,
            client_properties={
                'connection_name': self.get_connection_name(),
            }
        )

        self.connection = None
        self.channels = {}
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        if not self.connection or self.connection.is_closed:
            self.connection = BlockingConnection(self.parameters)
            self.close_channels()
            self.declare_channels()

    def declare_channels(self):
        for i in range(self.get_channel_count()):
            self.channels[i] = self.assign_channel()

    def send(self, message):
        try:
            self.connect()
            self.thread_safe_publish(message)
        except Exception as e:
            Log.e(f"Failed to send message to RabbitMQ: {e}")

    def assign_channel(self):
        if not self.connection or self.connection.is_closed:
            self.connect()
            return None
        channel = self.connection.channel(channel_number=None)
        channel.exchange_declare(
            exchange=self.get_rabbitmq_exchange_name(),
            exchange_type=self.get_rabbitmq_exchange_type(),
            durable=True,
        )
        return channel

    def thread_safe_publish(self, message):
        try:
            random_channel_number = CommonUtils.get_random_number(0, self.get_channel_count() - 1)
            channel = self.channels[random_channel_number]
            if not channel or channel.is_closed:
                channel = self.assign_channel()
                if channel:
                    self.channels[random_channel_number] = channel
            self.channels[random_channel_number].basic_publish(
                exchange=self.get_rabbitmq_exchange_name(),
                routing_key=self.get_rabbitmq_routing_key(),
                body=json.dumps(message),
                properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                    delivery_mode=2,  # make message persistent
                )
            )
            event_key = self.get_event_key()
            self.process_data_events(event_key)
        except Exception as e:
            Log.e(f"Failed to send message to RabbitMQ: {e}")

    def process_data_events(self, event_key):
        try:
            if not self.connection or self.connection.is_closed:
                self.connect()
            self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=0)
            import time
            CacheUtils.set_key_payload(key=event_key, payload=int(TimeUtils.current_milli_time()))
        except Exception as e:
            Log.e(str(e))

    def close_channels(self):
        try:
            if self.channels:
                for key, channel in self.channels.items():
                    if channel.is_open:
                        channel.close()
        except Exception as e:
            Log.e(str(e))
        self.channels = {}

    @abstractmethod
    def get_rabbitmq_routing_key(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_rabbitmq_exchange_name(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_rabbitmq_exchange_type(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_queue_message_type(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_event_key(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_channel_count(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_connection_name(self):
        pass

class EmailPublisher(RabbitMQProducer):
    __singleton_instance = None

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls):
        # check for the singleton instance
        if not cls.__singleton_instance:
            cls.__singleton_instance = EmailPublisher()
        # return the singleton instance
        return cls.__singleton_instance

    def get_rabbitmq_routing_key(self):
        return 'email.queue'

    def get_rabbitmq_exchange_name(self):
        return 'email_exchange'

    def get_rabbitmq_exchange_type(self):
        return "direct"

    def get_channel_count(self):
        return 5

    def get_connection_name(self):
        return 'email_connection'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to share the rabbitmq connection between gunicorn workers how can I do this?

**You can't!**

Gunicorn workers are *separate operating system processes*. Every worker must have its own connection to RabbitMQ.